# swift from array UserDefaults to tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have UserDefaults array as [[String: Any]]
How in swift I can pass from array to tableView for indexPath of row?

I pass

```
 if let loadedCart = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "cartt") as? [[String: Any]] {
        //            print(loadedCart)  // [[price: 19.99, qty: 1, name: A], [price: 4.99, qty: 2, name: B]]"
        for item in loadedCart {
            print(item["name"]  as! String)    // A, B
            //                print(item["price"] as! Double)    // 19.99, 4.99
            //                print(item["qty"]   as! Int)
            //                print(item["image"]   as! Int)  // 1, 2

            cell.textLabel?.text = item["name"] as? String
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item["price"] as? String
            cell.idLbl.text = item["qty"] as? String
```

but this not not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Declare a data source array on the top level of the class

  ```
  var loadedCart = [[String:Any]]()
  ```
- In `viewDidLoad` load the data from `UserDefaults` and reload the table view

  ```
  loadedCart = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "cartt") as? [[String: Any]] ?? []
  tableView.reloadData()
  ```
- In `numberOfRows` return

  ```
  return loadedCart.count
  ```
- In `cellForRow` get the item from the array and assign the values

  ```
  let item = loadedCart[indexPath.row]
  cell.textLabel?.text = item["name"] as? String
  cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item["price"] as? String
  cell.idLbl.text = item["qty"] as? String
  ```

If the array contains only `String` values declare the array as `[[String:String]]` and remove the optional downcast in `cellForRow`. However it's highly recommended to use a custom struct or class instead of the dictionary.